# Handling exceptions in Prism 4 modules

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, prism, mef

I've gone through a number of threads here about this topic with no success. It seems that in the App.xaml.cs of our WPF application, handling DispatcherUnhandledExceptions and AppDomain.CurrentDomain.UnhandledException don't catch everything.

In this specific instance we have 7 prism modules. My exception handling code is below (almost identical for UnhandledException):

```
private void OnDispatcherUnhandledException(object sender, DispatcherUnhandledExceptionEventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            var ex = e.Exception.InnerException ?? e.Exception;
            var logManager = new LogManager();
            logManager.Error(ex);


            if (!EventLog.SourceExists(ex.Source))
                EventLog.CreateEventSource(ex.Source, "AppName");
            EventLog.WriteEntry(ex.Source, ex.InnerException.ToString());

            var emb = new ExceptionMessageBox(ex);
            emb.ShowDialog();
            e.Handled = true;

        }
        catch (Exception)
        { }
    }
```

**The problem seems to be the unhandled exceptions occurring in the modules.** 
They aren't caught by the code above and they cause the application to crash without logging or displaying any sort of message.

Does anyone have experience with this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is what we did in our Prism app to catch exceptions (it catches almost everything):

```
static class Program
{
    [STAThread]
    static void Main()
    {
        try
        {
             App app = new App();
             app.InitializeComponent();
             app.Run();
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
             // Log here
             // Custom error message.
        }
     }
 }
```

For this to work you have to change your "Startup Object" to be this class.  You can do that in the shell's project properties.

Comment: This does partially work so I will give credit. However, in my situation this did not catch exceptions thrown from modules or from Parallel tasks. We now have MANY try catches.

Answer (score 0):

Though not perfect, you can trap exceptions that occurring during Module initialization by overriding `InitializeModules`.

```
protected override void InitializeModules()
{
    try
    {
        base.InitializeModules();
    }
    catch (ModuleInitializeException e)
    {
        Exception innerException = e.InnerException;

        // Handle Exception
    }
}
```

A `ModuleInitializeException` is thrown that can be trapped; the inner exception will contain the original exception.

Unfortunately `InitializeModules` or the module manager will perform its own logging, which in my case I'd prefer to do myself to avoid having the `ModuleInitializeException` show up in the log.